# Connecting to database with Jetty and JNDI/JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jetty

I am trying to migrate from glassfish to jetty.  I am trying to setup connection pools within jetty to access an oracle database with JPA.  When i have all the connection information in the persistence.xml, the connection works and i can access the database so I know the database drivers are working.  However some apps use JNDI to lookup the data source like the example below.

When i run it the EntityManager is null at em.createNativeQuery(queryString, Config.class).getResultList();.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DATA_SOURCE" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>testData</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Java:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "configDAO")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigDAO implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    public String getGroupEmailList() {
        return getConfigByName(FileUtils.EMAIL_LIST).getConfigValue();
    }

    public Config getConfigByName(String configName) {
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM CONFIG WHERE CONFIG_NAME = '" + configName + "'";
        List<Config> configList = em.createNativeQuery(queryString, Config.class).getResultList(); 
        if (configList != null && !configList.isEmpty()) {
            return configList.get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

In my jetty.xml in $JETTY_HOME/etc

```
<New id="testData" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg/>
    <Arg>testData</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
            <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:data</Set>
            <Set name="User">user</Set>
            <Set name="Password">password</Set>
            <Set name="ConnectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
            <Set name="ConnectionCacheProperties">
                <New class="java.util.Properties">
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">InactivityTimeout</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">300</Arg>
                    </Call>
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">AbandonedConnectionTimeout</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">600</Arg>
                    </Call>
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">TimeToLiveTimeout</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">600</Arg>
                    </Call>
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">InitialLimit</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">10</Arg>
                    </Call>
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">MaxStatementsLimit</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">50</Arg>
                    </Call>
                    <Call name="setProperty">
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">MinLimit</Arg>
                        <Arg type="java.lang.String">20</Arg>
                    </Call>
                </New>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Comment: What version of Jetty? (as editing of `${jetty.home}` is *strongly discouraged* since Jetty 9.x)

Comment: jetty-9.2.12.v20150709, where should i add my data source?